# VSTO C#: How to disable the popup (tooltip) on a Ribbon Button

Tags: button, vsto, tooltip, ms-office, ribbon

I developed a plugin for outlook 2007 that adds a button to the office ribbon.

I wanted to know if there is any possibility (programmatically) to not show the popup message when hoovering over the button with the mouse pointer.

When I hover over the button, a little popup (tooltip) with the following text is displayed: MyAddinName Press F1 for help

Is there any way to suppress this message for this custom button?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to remove that text.  Microsoft puts it there so that third-party add-ins are clearly identified and their product doesn't get blamed for buggy behavior.